# Wierd behavior of db2ls when run from directory containing spaces

Tags: db2

I am facing a strange issue with getting the db2 version using db2ls.
Below are 2 instances of db2ls execution

```
[root@dummy 6]# cd /tmp
[root@dummy tmp]# db2ls

Install Path                       Level   Fix Pack   Special Install Number       Install Date                  Installer UID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  -----------------------------------------
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5               10.5.0.3        3                            Tue Mar 10 01:38:53 2015 PDT             0

[root@dummy tmp]# mkdir test\ dir
[root@dummy tmp]# cd test\ dir/
[root@dummy test dir]# db2ls
/usr/local/bin/db2ls: line 43: cd: /tmp/test: No such file or directory

Install Path                       Level   Fix Pack   Special Install Number   Install Date                  Installer UID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5               10.5.0.3        3                            Tue Mar 10 01:38:53 2015 PDT             0
```

It looks like db2ls is having issues when executed from a directory having spaces. Is this a known issue? I could not find any documentation for this. I am trying to circumvent this problem by using db2ls 2>/dev/null.

If there is a more efficient way please let me know.

Comment: You should open a PMR with IBM for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0023683.html

for DB2 installation paths it says

> DB2 installation paths have the following rules:
>
> ```
> Can include lowercase letters (a-z), uppercase letters (A-Z), and the underscore character ( _ )
> Cannot exceed 128 characters
> Cannot contain spaces
> Cannot contain non-English characters
> ```

Reading statements like this are always a warning sign not to use spaces in paths in general. BTW, shell scripts don't play well with spaces in paths which is for me a good reason to avoid spaces in general.